# Sources of Min-Cost Flow Models That Utilize Binary Variables for Transportation Networks

Tags: reference-request, combinatorial-optimization, binary-variable, network-flow

I am looking for articles that include min-cost flow models with binary variables for flow transportation like gas networks, traffic systems, heating systems. Is there any specific place(like OR Library) where I can find all related articles? Can you share articles you know, that use min-cost flow models which implement binary variables for transportation networks?

Comment: Why do you specifically want binaries ? [Network Flows](https://cs.yazd.ac.ir/hasheminezhad/STSCS4R1.pdf) by Ahuja et al. is a great reference.

Comment: Such a network model typically gives automatic integer solutions. If your model has side-constraints that destroy the network structure, then you may consider using a MIP model.

Comment: @Kuifje Because binaries are perfect for representing 1/0-switches/valves in the flow control. Your reference is a book, do you reference specific pages/sections?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I plan to use MIP Network models already, I would like to see current implementations

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking: are you interested in models in which, if an arc is used, then the flow along that arc uses all its capacity? But what if there is not enough capacity downstream to absorb that much flow? I don't understand where the binary variables would enter the picture... you will "always" need some integer or real variables to kkep track of how much flow is being sent along an arc.

Comment: @AlbertoSantini Binary variables are used to make flow on/off, which represent valves/switches in real life. I would like to see models like MIPs (also possible implementations) that use them for this purpose. By the way, regarding your comment, Integer/real variables could be in the model, that is okay, that is not the area I am interested in.

Comment: I think the question is still unclear, but maybe the Fixed-Charge Network Flow problem resembles what you have in mind...